# Evaluate elements according to their order

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I would like to evaluate elements that hold a number value in my List according to their order (order by their value) and put them into List, where Key is the original element and Value is evaluated order. My problem is I don't know how to deal with indifferent values in elements - they should be an average order.

For example:

`double[]{2,4,4,4,7,8,40}` and I would like to have `double[]{1,3,3,3,5,6,7}`

I have already sorted that list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CriterionsNumber; i++)
{
    variants[i].Criterions.OrderByDescending(value => value.Value).ToList();
}

Thank you.
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do, or what is wrong with the code you posted here. One thing that stands out though, `OrderByDescending` returns a sorted list, it doesn't affect the source data at all.

Comment: What should it do if there were only 2 elements with the value 4? Then the average order would be 2.5.

Comment: @HansKilian Yes, if there would be 2 elements with value 4, it would looks like: int[]{1,2.5,2.5,4,5,6}. I already have an ordered list with order (as indexes), but I have to evaluate those elements with their order as there can be two same values.

Comment: It's kind of hard to put 2.5 into an array of ints

Comment: @HansKilian Oh yea, my bad. It was just a simple example to show what I want to have. In my Variant-Criteiron structure, there are of course double values.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I have already sorted the list of variants. But I need to get their order considering the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compute `Rank` for each item: having `{2,4,4,4,7,8,40}` to get

- `{1,2,2,2,5,6,7}` (*min* as tie breaker)
- `{1,3,3,3,5,6,7}` (*average* as tie breaker)
- `{1,4,4,4,5,6,7}` (*max* as tie breaker)

**Linq** solution; since you want to break tie by computing *average*, let's use `Average`:

```
  int[] source = new int[] { 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 40};

  List<int> result = source
    .OrderBy(item => item)
    .Select((item, index) => new { item, index = index + 1})
    .GroupBy(item => item.item, item => item.index)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Select(x => (int)(group.Average())))
    .ToList();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7
```

Put `Min` or `Max` instead of `Average` to have a different *tie breaker*

Answer (score 0):

This function gets the index sorted but when the value is repeated, it gets the average value. I think it is what you meant. Beware that the average index can be a fraction like 2.5 (otherwise you will have to add your rounding):

```cs
public void SortAverageIndex(double[] ArrayIn, out double[] ArrayOut)
        {

             Array.Sort(ArrayIn);

            ArrayOut = new double[ArrayIn.Length]; 

            int prevIndex = 0;
            double prevVal = ArrayIn[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < ArrayIn.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ArrayIn[i] != prevVal)
                {
                    double AverageIndex = (i + prevIndex - 1) / 2.0 +1;
                    prevVal = ArrayIn[i];
                    int index = prevIndex;
                    for (int j = prevIndex; j < i; j++)
                        ArrayOut[j] = AverageIndex;

                    prevIndex = i;
                }
            }

            double AverageIndexFinal = (ArrayIn.Length + prevIndex-1) / 2.0 + 1;            
            for (int j = prevIndex; j < ArrayIn.Length; j++)
                ArrayOut[j] = AverageIndexFinal;

        }
```